# Define season from date independent of year in VB

Tags: vb.net, vba, date

I am trying to define date stamps to a season (summer, winter, rut) using Access 2013 in a Module.  The 'seasons' have the same start and end date across different years and are defined below.

```
11/15 to 3/5 = Winter
3/16 to 10/15 = Summer
10/16 to 11/14 = Rut
```

The function included below first deals with null values and then formats the date time stamp as a simple month day (i.e. November 15th is formatted to 11/15).

I then define `tmpSeason as a String` and use nested If statements to classify each range of dates to the respective season.  Herein lies the problem.  Although the code runs, it results in a column with all "Winter" values.  I suspect the error stems from the lack of a year when using >= or <=.

```
Function Season(GPSFixTime)
   Dim tmpDt As Date

            If (IsNull(GPSFixTime) = True) Then
            Exit Function
            Else
            End If

        tmpDt = DateSerial(Mid(GPSFixTime, 1, 4), Val(Mid(GPSFixTime, 6, 2)), Val(Mid(GPSFixTime, 9, 2)))
        tmpDt = tmpDt + ((tmpHr / 24) - 7 / 24) 'To correct the time to local time in winter
        tmpDt = Format(tmpDt, "mm/dd") ' Format to remove year

   Dim tmpSeason As String
             If (tmpDt >= 11 / 15 Or tmpDt <= 2 / 15) Then
              tmpSeason = "Winter"
             Else
             If (tmpDt >= 3 / 15 Or tmpDt <= 10 / 15) Then
              tmpSeason = "Summer"
               Else
             If (tmpDt > 10 / 15 Or tmpDt < 11 / 15) Then
              tmpSeason = "Rut"

            End If
            End If
            End If

Season = tmpSeason

End Function
```

Any thoughts on how to properly classify dates to a season would be appreciated.

This is one of my initial posts regarding VBA and I welcome feedback in making a functional post.

Comment: start by deciding if it is VBA **or** VB.NET, then whether it is Northern or Southern Hemisphere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formatting string is wrong, you should use `MM` for the month compontent, `mm` will use the minutes component:

```
tmpDt = Format(tmpDt, "MM/dd")
```

In your comparisons you are trying to compare a string with an expression that looks similar to what's in the string, but is actually completely different.

The expression `11 / 15` for example doesn't represent a date, it will evaluate as a division, and the result is `0.733333333333333`. So, you are comparing the date string to numbers.

As you have formatted the date in a way that actually is comparable as strings, you can compare the date strings to the strings that represent the boundaries of the seasons:

```
If tmpDt >= "11/15" Or tmpDt <= "03/05" Then
  tmpSeason = "Winter"
ElseIf tmpDt >= "03/16" And tmpDt <= "10/15" Then
  tmpSeason = "Summer"
ElseIf tmpDt >= "10/16" And tmpDt <= "11/14" Then
  tmpSeason = "Rut"
End If
```

Note that you should use the `And` operator to check the two boundaries of a range, and `Or` for the condition for winter that is actually two separate ranges with only an upper bound for one and a lower bound for the other.

There is a gap in your dates from 03/06 to 03/15, I don't know if that is intentional. If it's wrong, you would adjust the code to use the correct dates, and if it's correct you might want to choose some other string to display during that time.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer and improvements to my code.  Much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

You have (at least) two options: either take the current year to build the boundaries of the seasons, or do the opposite - find the day of the year for the current date as well as the day of the year for the season boundaries and compare those.